# Parsing JSON data into html page with getJSon function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, symfony

I'm trying to make maybe the simplest jQuery's getJson function and I'm facing some problems..

my script:

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function()
     { 
         $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/api/tests', function(Results) 
     {
        document.write(Results.name);
        });
     });

</script>
```

I have tried to include *jquery.js* with multiple different ways.
for example:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*`Localhost:8000/api/tests`* prints out: `[{"id" :1, "name":"test", "description":"testtext"}]`

in app/config I have

```
assetic:
  assets:
    jquery: "%kernel.root_dir%/.../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min/js"
```

Probably nothing to do with this but if I add **-** front of the `jquery` **ERROR:** "The attribute "name" must be set for path "assetic.assets"

**Current result**:  `undefined`

Any tips how I make it display result as I want.. in this case instead of `undefined` it should be `test`

Hopefully you understand my question. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{"id" :1, "name":"test", "description":"testtext"}]
```

That's an array containing an object.

```
document.write(Results.name)
```

That tries to treat the array as if it was the object contained it it.

You need to get at the object out of the array first.

```
document.write(Results[0].name)
```

---

NB:

- By convention, variable names starting with a capital letter in JavaScript are reserved for Constructor Functions. Call your variable `results` instead.
- `document.write` will, unless run while the document is being constructed, destroy the existing document. This is almost always undesirable. You should probably use DOM instead.